# Service Fabric stateless ASP.net core is actually creating a .net framework project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric

I created a service fabric project in Visual Studio 2017 and tried to add an asp.net core service like below

[asp.net core 2.0 framework is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUd2A.png)

But framework which is selected for the project is .netframework 4.6.1. I am not sure reason for this discrepancy.

[.net framework 4.6.1 is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC16b.png)

I am not sure reason for this discrepancy?